# Regex for the following pattern

Tags: regex

I want to exclude if it is word, but want to include single character .

My Regex:

```
(\d{2})\[\.\](\d+)\[\.\](\d+|\d\w+)\[\.\]\.
```

I am getting:

`16.03.01a.SPA.bin`   -->  `16.03.01aS`

`03.17.00.S.156-1.S-std.bin`   -->  `03.17.00S`

`03.16.04a.S.155-3.S4a-ext.bin`   -->  `03.16.04aS`

Expected Output:

`16.03.01a.SPA.bin`   -->  `16.03.01a`

`03.17.00.S.156-1.S-std.bin`   -->  `03.17.00S`

`03.16.04a.S.155-3.S4a-ext.bin`   -->  `03.16.04aS`

The first one is taking single character from word, but i don't want it.

Comment: The `[.].` at the end of your regular expression matches a period followed by any other character. You could try something like `(\d{2})\.(\d+)\.(\d\w+)(?=\..)` depending on the engine you are using.

Comment: The last . is giving the single character, but i don't want in the first output. I don't know what i need to put there. That's why i put '.' there

Comment: Please indicate what language or tool you're using, and show the code that performs the transformation you're depicting (since a transformation involves more than just a regex).

Comment: How about [this one](http://regexr.com/3ehfl)?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want, i don't know how to thank you. I am trying for last 5 hours. Thank you so much.. Can you please explain, how is it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you are looking for the following regular expression:

```
(\d{2})\.(\d+)\.(\d\w*)(?:\.(.)(?=\.)|)
```

Broken down, this is:

```
(\d{2})             Match 2 digits
\.                  Match a period
(\d+)               Match 1 or more digits
\.                  Match a period
(\d\w*)             Match a digit followed by 0 or more word characters
(?:
    \.              Match a period
    (.)(?=\.)       Match a single character (as long as the following character is a period)
    |               OR match nothing at all
)
```